# How to executed a PERFORM statement depending on value only once

Tags: arrays, cobol

I have the following problem and cannot find the right solution for it.

I have a Dataset (thousands of lines) with a column that has different values ('MO' or 'BO').
Now I want to go through all lines and check whether the value in that column can be found in a table/array that will be filled with the value that was extracted from the step before.
If that value was already added to the table, a further step must not be executed.

I would like to achieve that the PERFORM will only be triggered once.

Now my problem is that the "NOT" condition is always false and although the value in SHORTCODE was already added to WS-CODE it is still added.
And the only thing that I would like to have is to add distinctive values to my table.

This is what I got so far:

```
01 WS-TABLE
  05 WS-CODE PIC X(4) OCCURS 100 TIMES INDEXED BY I.
  05 WS-ANZ  PIC 9(8)
  05 SW-SUBPROD  PIC X(1).
    88 CODE-FOUND VALUE '0'.
    88 CODE-NOTF VALUE '1'.
  01 COLUMN-VALUE PIC X(4).

MOVE COLUMN-VALUE TO SHORTCODE
SET I TO 1

SEARCH CODE
     WHEN SHORTCODE NOT = WS-CODE(I)
          MOVE SHORTCODE TO WS-CODE(ANZ)
          ADD 1 TO ANZ   
          SET CODE-NOTF TO TRUE
END-SEARCH

IF CODE-NOTF  
   PERFORM DO-SOME-TASK
END-IF
```

Sample data is (Dataset):

```
0101459 MO
0101460 MO
0104610 BO
```

Comment: Please supply Data definitions, sample data and expected results. I assume you have done this already to test your code?

Comment: Yes, sure.
So far everything is running, but maybe I do not understand the index (I) in WS-CODE.

Comment: I added the Data definitions and some data.
So far everything is running, but somehow the NOT condition is not working as expected. Maybe I understand the SEARCH and Index in Cobol wrong.

Comment: Maybe, I understand it now.
After having found the first occurence in the table, it should stop from checking the next value and just adding the "not found value".
Can I somehow break the loop with NEXT SENTENCE or CONTINUE?

Comment: Until you post complete compilable code with test data that runs, and has expected results then  it is difficult to help you. I don't have Cobol set up as a test environment here so I will need to run it in an online environment. It is many years since I have used COBOL but I used it professionally for over a decade. :) It brings back good memories. You can always put your code / testdata / expected results in 'Pastebin' or equivalent. :) I am not going to write your code and tests for you. I don't mind debugging and  helping you to understand.

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question with the pseudocode you have provided.  You ask, "Can I somehow break the loop..." but there is no looping construct in the code presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a few hints in the code supplied, it appears that you want to add *unique* values to a table and `PERFORM DO-SOME-TASK` only when a value is added to the table. The `SEARCH` statement in the code below determines whether, or not, the value is present in the table. The following `IF` statement adds the value if it was not found by the `SEARCH`. After adding the value, the `PERFORM` statement is executed.

```
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 WS-TABLE.
      05 WS-CODE PIC X(4) VALUE SPACES
           OCCURS 100 TIMES INDEXED BY I.
      05 WS-ANZ  PIC 9(8) VALUE 0.
      05 SW-SUBPROD  PIC X(1) VALUE '1'.
        88 CODE-FOUND VALUE '0'.
        88 CODE-NOTF VALUE '1'.
   01 COLUMN-VALUE PIC X(4).
   01 SHORTCODE PIC X(4).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       MOVE "MO" TO COLUMN-VALUE
       PERFORM DO-LOOKUP
       MOVE "MO" TO COLUMN-VALUE
       PERFORM DO-LOOKUP
       MOVE "BO" TO COLUMN-VALUE
       PERFORM DO-LOOKUP
       STOP RUN
       .

   DO-LOOKUP.
       MOVE COLUMN-VALUE TO SHORTCODE
       SET I TO 1

       SEARCH WS-CODE
           AT END
               SET CODE-NOTF TO TRUE
           WHEN WS-CODE (I) = SHORTCODE
               SET CODE-FOUND TO TRUE
       END-SEARCH

       IF CODE-NOTF
           ADD 1 TO WS-ANZ
           MOVE SHORTCODE TO WS-CODE (WS-ANZ)
           PERFORM DO-SOME-TASK
       END-IF
       .

   DO-SOME-TASK.
       CONTINUE
       .
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
Yes, that is what I was trying to fulfill, creating unique entries in a table!